# how to check if specific array key exist in multidimensional array then append that array into new array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional array e.g. (this can be many levels deep) and another array to be appended like this:

```
$another_array = array();
$array = array(
    [1] => array ()
    [2] => array ()
    [3] => array (
        [4] => array (
            [5] => array (
                [8] => array()
            )
        )
    )
)
);
```

I am trying to loop through it to see if a certain key exists then array append to another array

```
$another_array = array(); 
$keysearch = 8;

function findKey($item, $keysearch){
    foreach($array as $key => $item){
        if($key == $keysearch){
            $another_array[] = $array[$key]; // append array to another array
        }else if(is_array($item) && var_dump(findKey($item, $keysearch))==true){
            $another_array[] = $item; // append array to another array
        }
    }
}
```

Output I want

```
$another_array = [0] => array (
                [4] => array (
                    [5] => array (
                        [8] => array()
                    )
                )
            )
```

But it finds nothing and not append it.

Comment: Should `findKey($item, $keysearch){` not be `function findKey($item, $keysearch){`

Comment: @RiggsFolly  means?

Comment: `findKey()` is never called in the code you've shown.  Are you actually calling it, and if so, with what parameters?

Comment: @Don'tPanic okay. I trying to excute  `findKey($array, $keysearch);` ..still nothing and not append to`$another_array`

Comment: _means?_ You didnt create a function you just called a non-existant functoin :)

Comment: ... and you then edited the question to fix the error @RiggsFolly described! :-)

Comment: @RiggsFolly hmmm

Comment: Hi `m`. Do you mean to find a matching node then copy the *path* to it from root?

Comment: Your function is not returning anything at all. Even if you passed that array as an argument then the function wouldn't even modify that array because those are passed by value by default

Comment: @ITgoldman yes. i think so.

Comment: @DarkBee  do you have any suggestion code to fix this?

Comment: @Don'tPanic  I panic right now because I do not find answer huhu :(

Comment: Since question is closed, maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36768921/building-paths-from-multidimensional-array-in-php which finds *all* the paths, but could be useful

Comment: Hey ! do not close this question until  you give the code >:(